# Discontinuity of principal argument in nonpositive real axis

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, complex-numbers

Let $\operatorname{Arg}(z)$ be principal argument function defined in branch $(-\pi, \pi]$.
Prove that $\operatorname{Arg}(z)$ is discontinuous in every point in nonpositive real axis.

"Solution":
Let $z_0$ be a point on the nonpositive part of real axis.
By $z$ approaching $z_0$ "from below" the $\operatorname{Arg}(z)$  reaches $\pi$
By $z$ approaching $z_0$ "from top" the $\operatorname{Arg}(z)$  reaches $-\pi$
Therefore for two given paths $\operatorname{Arg}(z)$ has two different limits.
Therefore $\operatorname{Arg}(z)$ has no limit.

Can you please help me find more rigorous solution which specifically bases on
$\operatorname{Arg}(z) = \arctan\left(\frac{y}{x}\right) + \pi$?
I understand that I have to find two paths for which $$\lim_{x \to x_0, \  y \to y_0}\operatorname{Arg}(z)$$ does not exist. But what are they?

Answer (score 1):

> more rigorous solution which specifically bases on $\operatorname{Arg}(z)=\arctan(y/x)+\pi$?

The problem with using $\arctan(y/x)$ is that it's actually continuous across the negative real axis; its discontinuities are along the imaginary axis.

To make the branch cut you want, the definition should be like this:
 $$ \operatorname{Arg}(z)=\begin{cases} \arctan(y/x),\quad &x>0
\\
\arctan(y/x) + \pi,\quad &x<0, \ y>0 \\
\arctan(y/x) - \pi,\quad &x<0, \ y<0  \\
\pi/2,\quad &x=0, \ y>0 \\
-\pi/2,\quad &x=0, \ y<0  
\end{cases}$$

You can check that these pieces match on both halves of the imaginary axis. Along the negative real axis, $\arctan(y/x)$ is continuous but $\pi$ clashes with $-\pi$.

As for the paths, two vertical paths will do

- Along $x=x_0$, $y=y_0+t$, where $t\to 0^+$, we get $\operatorname{Arg} \to \pi$
- Along $x=x_0$, $y=y_0+t$, where $t\to 0^-$, we get $\operatorname{Arg} \to -\pi$